# Loading html and php page in div

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

How can I load html in a div when I click a button?

I have function but it does not work:

```
function ajaxFunction(id, url){
document.getElementById("sh").style.visibility = 'hidden';
    var xmlHttp;
    try {// Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
        xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();     
    } catch (e) {// Internet Explorer
        try {
            xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            try {
                xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e) {
                alert("Your browser does not support AJAX!");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {
            //Get the response from the server and extract the section that comes in the body section of the second html page avoid inserting the header part of the second page in your first page's element
            var respText = xmlHttp.responseText.split('<body>');
            elem.innerHTML = respText[1].split('</body>')[0];
        }
    }

    var elem = document.getElementById(id);
    if (!elem) {
        alert('The element with the passed ID doesn\'t exists in your page');
        return;
    }

    xmlHttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlHttp.send(null);
}
```

And I have button to click it.

```
<button type="button" name="new metere" value="" class="button" onclick="ajaxFunction('test','newmetere.html');">new metere</button>
```

when I put newmetere.php Function does not work and get garbage value.

Comment: I hate to be 'that guy', but you might want to look at jQuery. Before anyone gets angry, that means you are straight away into modern tutorials and jQuery encourages event binding rather than onclick type stuff.

Comment: You mention newmetere.php fails to load but i'm assuming the .html extension in your example works. Simple points but are you sure your server is serving .php correctly? Can you visit the newmetere.php page directly? What is the output there? Are you 100% sure there's no typos?

Answer (score 0):

Try [jQuery's load ()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) : it's a fast and simple way to load content from another page asynchronously in a web page using Ajax!